# LIRC coflict with device tree?

Tags: lirc

I have tried to set up LIRC with Raspberry PI 2B for a couple of days now with no luck.   The receiver works fine, but not the IR emitter.     This is what I figured out, if I turned off device tree with "device_tree=" in config.txt, LIRC works fine with the right pin assignment.

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio
[sudo] password for root: 
GPIOs 0-53, bcm2708_gpio:
 gpio-17  (lirc_rpi ir/out     ) in  lo    
 gpio-18  (lirc_rpi ir/in      ) in  lo    
 gpio-47  (led0                ) out lo
```

and following is when I leave the device tree on:

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio
[sudo] password for root: 
GPIOs 0-53, platform/3f200000.gpio, pinctrl-bcm2835:
 gpio-35  (?                   ) in  hi    
 gpio-47  (?                   ) out lo
```

Does anyone have any advice?  I need the device tree on since it is required for the touch display to work.

Comment: What device tree settings have you put in /boot/config.txt for LIRC?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used lirc but I can quote you some stuff that you should be able to find in `/boot/overlays/README`:

> Overlays are loaded using the "dtoverlay" directive. As an example,
>   consider the popular lirc-rpi module, the Linux Infrared Remote
>   Control driver. In the pre-DT world this would be loaded from
>   /etc/modules, with an explicit "modprobe lirc-rpi" command, or
>   programmatically by lircd. With DT enabled, this becomes a line in
>   config.txt:
>
> ```
> dtoverlay=lirc-rpi
> ```
>
> This causes the file /boot/overlays/lirc-rpi-overlay.dtb to be loaded.
>   By default it will use GPIOs 17 (out) and 18 (in), but this can be
>   modified using DT parameters:
>
> ```
> dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_out_pin=17,gpio_in_pin=13
> ```

You can have multiple `dtoverlay` lines; if there is a conflict I think the one that's later in `config.txt` will take precedence.  So as long as the right gpios are used in each case, you should be able to do this with the touchscreen.

Comment: that's how I works in jessie for me. I can't tell if it's still valid for stretch.